# FileStream not letting me create file on C drive

Tags: c#, filestream

I am using `FileStream` to create a file with given`Length`.`OpenFileDialog` to open a file and `FolderBrowserDialog` to get the Location. Now the problem is when I choose Location on D:\ or E:\ drive it successfully creates the file. But when I choose C:\ drive it gives an `Exception` like `UnauthorizedAccessException was unhandled.` 
  `C:\file.mp4 is denied.`
When I choose desktop as destination it gives no `Exception` and Does not create the file. I'm using this code

```
    private void createFile()
    {
        long size = fileInfo.Length;
        string name = file.FileName.Substring(file.FileName.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1, (file.FileName.Length - (file.FileName.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1)));
        string filename = "" + location.SelectedPath + name;

        FileStream outFile = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create);
        outFile.SetLength(size);
        outFile.Close();
    }
```

My UAC is disabled and Also I am an Administrator user.I'm using windows 8 pro. Can anybody explain what can be the solution ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you able to create that file in other ways, e.g. from a command prompt?

Comment: Can you create it through explorer?

Comment: On desktop Yes. But on c: Access denied. (using cmd)

Comment: Again using explorer there is only folder create option on C: drive.Is there any way to gain access and create file using c#.

Comment: Try command prompt in elevated mode, start -> run then type `runas /user:administrator cmd`. This is likely a permissions issue. Also (as a test) create a folder on C: and set the NTFS permission to full control for Everyone and try writing to this folder.

Comment: Try right clicking your application(exe file) and click run as administrator..

Comment: yap. When I run that .exe file as an administrator it can create. But if I want to run as user, is there any way I can gain access on c: drive.

Comment: You must enforce your  application to start in admin account.
see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16897395/c-creating-txt-file)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Permission issue. In case of Vista/Windows 7/8, `C:\` drive is considered as system, and you'll need elevated privileges for your process in order to create files directly under it. Try running your process or Visual Studio as Administrator, and it should work.

Hope it helps.

Comment: yap. When I run that .exe file as an administrator it can create. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on exe => Run as Administrator => Proceed => Check now.
It should work now.